# How to dynamically draw a separator on a pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart in Highcharts and I would like to have a separator between each slice and I can't figure out how to do this.

I know I can use borderWidth to do this but this also puts a border around the whole slice like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rymfdacp/1/

The only way I can think of is using chart.renderer.path to draw a line like this:

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', 301.9728096273067, 67.50000276897518,'L', 299.2807325002842, 107.16355788480266])//M 75 223.5 L 593 223.5
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 1.5,
            stroke: '#0a0a26'
        })
        .add();
```

You can see a full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rymfdacp/

Now what I would like, is to automatically render these lines to separate the slices / data.

Alternatively, if somebody has a better or more simple solution I would be all ears!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is to set border color the same as the background. Check demo posted below.

You can make it using the renderer, but this solution is much more difficult.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    styledMode: false,
    events: {
     load: function() {
       console.log(this);
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#fff',
      colors: [
        '#1cbbbe',
        '#1cbbbe',
      ],
      animation: false,
      innerSize: '70%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b><br />{point.name}',
        distance: 40,
        filter: {
          property: 'percentage',
          operator: '>',
          value: 3
        },
        style: {
          color: '#000',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '14px'
        },
        shadow: false,
        connectorShape: 'crookedLine',
        connectorColor: 'rgba(27, 186, 190, 0.5)'
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    floating: true,
    color: 'black',
    text: '<span class="title-first">Balance</span><br/>356<br/>Total Paid',
    x: 0,
    y: 180,
    style: {
      color: 'black',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: false,
    style: {
      zIndex: 25
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['Unconfirmed Balance', 9.2668],
      ['Unpaid Balance', 78.8788],
    ]
  }]
}, function(chart) { // on complete
  var gradient = {
    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 400],
    stops: [
      [0, '#1b4b5a'],
      [1, '#3a8293']
    ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3c7fw1uj/